# load_file function is not working in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in mysql and wanted to insert an image in mysql table cell but it is not updating.

```
update studentDetails set studentPic = LOAD_FILE('/images/picture.jpg') where studentID = 4;
```

Please help!

Comment: The file must exist on the computer where the MySQL server runs (this is not always the computer where the PHP code runs).

Comment: The argument of `LOAD_FILE()` must be the full path of the file in the file system. I guess `/images/picture.jpg` is the path component of the file URL. It is not the same as the absolute file path in the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick excerpt from the documentation of [`LOAD_FILE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) MySQL function:

> `LOAD_FILE(file_name)`
>
> Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the [`FILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) bytes. If the [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.
>
> If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns `NULL`.

AS you can see, there are myriads of reason your call to `LOAD_FILE()` fails:

1. The file must be present on the computer where the MySQL server runs. This is not always the same computer as the one where the PHP script runs (and this happens for security reasons). If they run on different computers then most probably you cannot use `LOAD_FILE()`. Case closed.

   *In theory you could use `FTP` or `SFTP` to transfer the file on the computer where MySQL runs but for the same security reasons, you probably don't have access to that computer.*
2. Assuming in your case both PHP and MySQL run on the same computer, `/images/picture.jpg` is the path component of the URL, not a path on the file system. You can use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to compose the path to the `images` directory starting from the path of the current script.
3. The user you use to connect to the MySQL server must have the [`FILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege. The privilege is granted to the user by a DBA.
4. The file must be readable by all. This is the easiest part. When you run `ls -l` on the file, the last three symbols in the column of file rights must be `rw-` or `r--` (there is no point having the executable bit set).
5. The default value of [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) system variable is `4 MiB` but a DBA can change it. You can run `SELECT @@max_allowed_packet FROM dual` to find out its current value.
6. If the [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) system variable is set then the path you provide must be relative to this directory. Again, you can run `SELECT @@secure_file_priv FROM dual` to find its current value.